# How to save file with default name and extention in pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to save a file but I'd like the file to have a default name unless the user chooses to change the name. The file extension mustn’t be changed. Here's what I've tried:

The issue is that it saves the file but not with default filename or extension.

```
def save(self):
    filename, extension = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileNameAndFilter(
        self, 'Save File', '.', filter=self.tr("Backup file (*.bak)"))
    with open("text.txt", 'r') as te, open(filename, "w") as backup:
        for line in te:
            backup.writelines(line)
```

Comment: Does it work? How do you know?

Comment: It saves the file but not with default filename or extension

Comment: What are the values of `filename` and `extension`?

Comment: filename is a Qtgui.Qfiledialog object, filter is just an option in the api

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't `filename` a string representing the chosen file name? What is it's value before calling `open(filename, "w")`? Do you need to append `extension` to it? What is the value of `extension`?

Comment: No, it's a class from pyqt that provides a dialog that allow users to select files or directories.

Comment: I tried using filter to set the extension but I think it only works that way for opening files, not saving them

Comment: In the code you have posted, `filename` is passed to `open`, and must be a string. It can't be a dialog.

Comment: yes, once the filename is chosen by the user, it becomes a string, that string will be the new save file's name

Comment: It is always a string, never anything else. What is its value?

Comment: it's just a <class 'PyQt4.QtCore.QString'> which can easily be converted to a python string with str(filename)

Comment: What is its value after converting with `str(filename)`?

Comment: That's why the file is saved without the extension. You need to concatenate the extension: `open(filename + extension, "w") as backup`

Comment: I will go try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to save with the default file name this way:

```
def save(self):
    filename, extension = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileNameAndFilter(
        self, 'Save file', 'backup_x', filter=self.tr(".bak"))
    try:
        with open("text.txt", 'r') as inst, open(filename + extension, "w") as backup:
            for line in inst:
                backup.writelines(line)
    except IOError:
        pass
```

Comment: what does `self.tr` refer to?

Comment: The `tr()` method is used to obtain the correct translation of a message. But you don't need to use it if your program is unilingual. More can be found there:http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/i18n.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the filename and the extension:

```
backup_name = filename + extension

with open("text.txt", 'r') as te, open(backup_name, "w") as backup:
    ...
```

Comment: That solves the extension issue when I change `("Backup file (*.bak)")` to just `.bak` but the default name I still don't know how to set. Thanks for the help in figuring this out!